# Is syscall splice atomic if only PIPE_BUF bytes is copied?

Tags: linux, pipe, splice

I know that writing less than or equal to `PIPE_BUF` bytes to pipe is atomic.

However there isn't any document on whether doing this using `splice` has the same behavior.

I wonder is it guaranteed that any write to the pipe (including `splice`, `sendfile`, `tee`) is atomic when the length is no longer than `PIPE_BUF`?